Is the name of God ONLY a 3rd person form of to be?
The name of the LORD is understood to be a 3rd person form of to be (see link below).
Another name is understood by some in first person - "I am" or "I will be".
Is there a second person name for the LORD?
Is the name of God simply a third person form of to be?

"The name of the LORD is understood to be a 3rd person form of to be (see link below)." The answers there clarify that that understanding is mistaken.

Sure. But, my broader question and core question is whether there are 2nd form relations to the LORD?

@Calvin so please accept DoubleAA's tochacha. Just say your core question
